# Show that the vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ , $\vec{c}$, $\vec{d}$ span the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$. Which vectors could be left out to get Basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, vectors, systems-of-equations

Show that the below vectors span the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$\vec{a} = (1,2,3)^T$$
$$\vec{b} = (2,6,10)^T$$
$$\vec{c} = (-1,-3,-5)^T$$
$$\vec{d} = (0,-3,-5)^T$$

Which of the vectors are not needed to get a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which are needed ?

---

We set up our matrix, for example using https://matrixcalc.org/en/

(https://matrixcalc.org/en/#rank(%7B%7B1,2,-1,0%7D,%7B2,6,-3,-3%7D,%7B3,10,-5,-5%7D%7D) )

We get

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 1 & -1/2 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Just a bit unsure here.
So the rank seems to be 3, but why exactly ? Also, is this row echelon form or reduced row echelon form ?

It has rank 3 so it spans $\mathbb{R}^3$. Either $\vec{b}$ or $\vec{c}$ can be left out because they are linearly dependent, the others aren't. We could set up a system, solve for the vector $(0,0,0,0)^T$ to see that either $b$ or $c$ are free variables.

So to prove that those vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$, we showed that the matrix has rank 3. Then we showed that $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are linearly dependent, so one of both can be left out to get a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$

---

Could you give me your feedback ?

Thanks for your support !

Comment: If you can get $(1,0,0)^T$, $(0,1,0)^T$, $(0,0,1)^T$ by linear combination of $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}, \vec{d}$, then they span $\mathbb{R}^3$. One can easily see that $\vec{b}=-2\vec{c}$, so one of these two vectors could be left out.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu To get the unit vectors by linear combination, do I just set up a matrix with the vector (1 0 0) resp. one of the two others to the right, and then solve to find the variables a, b, c, d ?

Comment: You can do it with matrix calculation but I suppose this can be done manually: $(1,0,0)=\vec{d}-\vec{c}$, ...

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Yes of course this one is rather easy but for the two others it seems less straightforward

Comment: Just take $a, c, d$ and for example you can see that $d - c = [1 ~0 ~ 0]$. Similarly you can see that $d - 3c - 3a = [0~0~1]$... similarly find a linear combination that leads to $[0 ~1 ~0]$

Comment: @MathLover Is it better to show that we can get to those unit vectors that span R^3 or show that the rank equals the number of dimensions (3 in this case fro R^3) ?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Is it better to show that we can get to those unit vectors that span R^3 or show that the rank equals the number of dimensions (3 in this case fro R^3) ?

Comment: It is a matter of taste. I like getting unit vectors much more than matrix rank calculations.